# How to make coded UI test to select newest folder in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I'm writing a coded ui test that is to act on a folder created every night. The way I want it to work is that the test will choose the newest folder.

How would I do this? Assertions?

The folder is being selected from a folder dialog box that I open with the main application. The name of the folder is then placed into a text box on the main app and scaned for patches.

```
 //Expand 'Computer' -> 'network drive (X:)' -> 'great-granparent' -> 'granparent' -> 'parent' -> 'folder' tree item
 uIfolder_TreeItem.Expanded = this.Browse_For_FolderParams.UIfolder_TreeItemExpanded;
```

Using nXu's code I've tried this:

```
 DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(@"X:\great-granparent\granparent\parent");
        DirectoryInfo[] folders = root.GetDirectories();

        DirectoryInfo newest = folders[0];
        foreach (var dir in folders)
        {
            if (dir.CreationTime.CompareTo(newest.CreationTime) > 0)
                newest = dir;
        }


        //Expand 'Computer' -> 'network drive (X:)' -> 'great-granparent' -> 'granparent' -> 'parent' -> 'folder' tree item
        newest = this.Browse_For_FolderParams(newest);
```

**End Code**

```
        DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(@"X:\great-granparent\granparent\parent");
        DirectoryInfo[] folders = root.GetDirectories();

        DirectoryInfo newest = folders[0];
        foreach (var dir in folders)
        {
            if (dir.CreationTime.CompareTo(newest.CreationTime) > 0)
                newest = dir;
        }


        uIfolder_TreeItem.SearchProperties["Name"] = newest.Name;

        //Expand 'Computer' -> 'network drive (X:)' -> 'great-granparent' -> 'granparent' -> 'parent' -> 'folder' tree item
        uIfolder_TreeItem.Expanded = this.Get_FolderParams.UIfolder_TreeItemExpanded;
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Look at the uIfolder_TreeItem member.  You want to do something like `uIfolder_TreeItem.SearchProperties["Name"] = newest.Name`, and exclude the newest = this.Browse_For_FolderParams(newest);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DirectoryInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx), it has CreationTime, LastAccessTime and LastWriteTime properties.
For example, to select the last created folder on C:\ root, use the following code:

```
DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
DirectoryInfo[] folders = root.GetDirectories();

DirectoryInfo max = folders[0];
foreach (var dir in folders)
{
    if (dir.CreationTime.CompareTo(max.CreationTime) > 0)
        max = dir;
}

// Last created directory is max
```

Comment: Where should I put this in the test?

Comment: If the Coded UI Test is testing an application in this new folder, you would place this wherever the application under test is launched.  For example, so I have a LaunchApp method, and it would contain nXu's code followed by:
`ApplicationUnderTest testApplication = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(exePath);` and using max in nXu's code, you could build the exePath string.

Comment: @Vi3GameHkr The folder is being selected from a folder dialog box that I open with the main application. The folder from the dialog box and then its scaned by the main application. The only different step is that the folder is created everyday and the newest one has to be scaned. I'll update my question

Comment: Okay, you can still use nXu's code to get the name of the latest directory, and use that name to find the folder to click in the file dialog box.  I'm assuming you have some method in the UIMap that selects the folder?  I would use this code at the top of that method.  I'm assuming you are already able to navigate to the parent folder of the folder in question.

Comment: @Vi3GameHkr I have a recorded method that selects the folder automatically I picked. I want it to pick the newest folder. I've added code to my question hoping to make it more clear to you what i have.